# How to consolidate celery logs from different computers. CELERY

Tags: python, flask, celery, python-logging, celery-log

How do I get logs from different workers in a single file in Celery.
I have 3 workers running python tasks and a master node which runs the broker. I want to consolidate logs from these worker machines and store it in the master machine. How can I do that?

Comment: There's a large list of log consolidation tools and services: AWS Cloud Watch, Papertrail, Datadog, rsyslog, etc. You need to determine what you're trying to do and why so that you can choose the best one for your needs.

Comment: I'm not using AWS nor any cloud solutions. Will Logstash serve this purpose of collecting logs from different sources and store them at a single place?

Answer (score 0):

We have all our Celery workers on AWS EC2 instances configured to upload Celery logs to CloudWatch. This is one way to achieve what you want. It is not difficult to implement this kind of system even if you are not on AWS - all you need is an agent running on each worker machine that periodically uploads Celery logs to central place. It can even be a cron-job running a script that does the job for you.